# Hide and show function not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari6

This function should stop displaying the `#bt_pagamento` and start showing the `#bt_loading`. But **Safari (version 6)** is the only browser that this function doesn't work. In early versions of **Safari** (**version 5.1.9 Mac** and **5.1.7 Win**) it worked perfectly.

```
$("#bt_pagamento").click(function () {
$(this).css({'display':'none'});
$("#bt_loading").show();
});
```

Does anyone know a work around for this?

Comment: Would using `$(this).hide();` change the outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
<style>
.hide { display: none; }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="bt_pagamento">link</a>
<div id="bt_loading" class="hide">
    this is bt_loading
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bt_pagamento").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('hide');
        $("#bt_loading").removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict()(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hide_value_discount_1').css('disabled','none');
    $('#bt_loading').click()(function(){

        if(document.getElementById('bt_pagamento').click()){
            $('#bt_loading').show('slow');  

        }else
            if(document.getElementById('bt_pagamento').click() == false){
             $('#bt_loading').css('display','none');    

            }

    });
    $('#bt_pagamento').click();
});
</script>


<a href="#" id="bt_pagamento">link</a>
<div id="bt_loading" class="hide">
    this is bt_loading
</div>
```