# HTML Button Highlight With Jquery Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I am currently in the process of building a web app. I am trying to get an image when clicked to change image source and then hide one div and show another. This seems to work fine when viewing within a browser but when viewed on an iPad the button image change doesn't work. An example of what I am currently doing is below:

```
$("#pg3rgt_en_GB").click(function(){
$(this).css("background-image","url(images/right-button-down.jpg)");
setTimeout(function(){
$("#introduction_en_GB").hide();
$("#pg3rgt_en_GB").css("background-image","url(images/right-button.jpg)");
$("#customerinput_en_GB").show();},250);
```

I hope that this is something simple I am missing. I appreciate any help and thanks in advance!

Comment: $("#pg3rgt_en_GB").css("background-image","url('images/right-button.jpg')"); add single quotes may work

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I have just tried this and no luck. for some reason when testing the highlight will work on the odd occasion.

Comment: missing }); at the end

Comment: Just checked my code and it was my mistake in copying it. It is there I just didn't copy it :/

Comment: the hide and show functions arent supported in Safari.  See the [Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) > Visual Effects... You'll need a CSS hack to change hide/show to visible:hidden and visible:visible

Comment: Thank you very much!! That explains a lot lol :D

Comment: See also: [Hide and show function not working in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736762/hide-and-show-function-not-working-in-safari), besides visible, you can use display:none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari doesn't recognise the show and hide features that jQuery has to offer. The best way around this would be to assign different css classes - which safari does recognise!