# Hiding DIVs using Jquery is not working in Safari (iOS)

Tags: jquery, html, ios, safari

I have written a fairly basic script that hides various field on an HTML form on document ready. This works just fine on my desktop machine and on my Kindle, but when trialling it on an iPad using Safari, none of the elements are hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Hide the editable field DIVs
    $("#form_location_edit").hide();
    $("#form_bin_no_edit").hide();
    $("#form_area_edit").hide();
    $("#form_quantity_edit").hide();
    $("#form_denomination_edit").hide();
    $("#form_comments_edit").hide();
    $("#form_responsible_edit").hide();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of Safari doesn't support `hide()` function. You can use CSS + `addClass()` function instead of it.

See: [Hide and show function not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736762/hide-and-show-function-not-working-in-safari)